# Problems with UICollectionView on IO9 if It is embedded in a table view

Tags: uicollectionview, swift2, ios9

Since my move to the new iOS9 and Xcode 7 I have  faced a problem with one of the `UICollectionView`in my app,

If I use it as `Nib( .xib )` file, it works fine,
but if I embed it in a `Table View`, the `Collection view cell` starts way before the first index.
I use a custom layout only for the snapping effect ,and then I let the flow layout handle the rest.

I have recreated the issue in a sample project and uploaded it to Dropbox, here is the link : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kqsobmg86z3pnhz/AAB52JnPgp1WflJsxqOJHEcZa?dl=0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found the solution:

In the custom UICollectionViewCell class I **override didMoveToSuperView()**

method to add this:

```
    self.setNeedLayout()
    self.layoutfNeeded()
```

and everything works fine.